# How does one "reprogram" a Frigidaire oven?

Tags: equipment, oven

We accidentally attempted to start the cleaning cycle on our Frigidaire Gallery double wall oven (model GLEB27T8ABA) while the lower oven door was open.  Thankfully, the oven did not actually turn on the heating element, but it did freak out.  The latches for both doors closed, and the oven is now running the fan , sounding an alarm and flashing error code F8 on the display every few minutes.  We got the upper latch to open by pressing that oven's cancel button, but the lower oven's latch is still closed.

The manual suggests pressing both cancel buttons at the same time and then "reprogramming" the oven, but it does not anywhere explain how to do that reprogramming.  So, the question:

How does one "reprogram" this model of oven, or otherwise resolve such an issue?

Comment: I’d recommend calling the company first.  Second thing to do would be unplugging it for a few minutes then plugging it back in

Comment: It is absolutely impossible that they would design an appliance you can brick (until reflashed) just by pressing two user-accessible buttons at the same time, if that's what you're worried about. Press the cancel buttons and then go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Neither research nor experimentation led me to a combination of button presses that resolved the issue, nor did I discover what the manual meant by the word "reprogram".  I did resolve the issue, however.

Other online sources suggested *resetting* the oven by unplugging it for a time.  I had tried this already, but I had left the power disconnected for only about 30 seconds.  That was not effective for me, but some sources suggested leaving the oven unpowered for ten minutes or more to effect a reset.

I actually left the oven unpowered for several hours, which I'm sure was overkill.  Additionally, though I'm uncertain whether it was necessary, we held down the door sensor switch while we restored power, on the theory that we would prevent the oven from recognizing the door open / latch closed fault condition.  When power was restored, the door latch started rotating. We held the sensor switch until the latch stopped (in the unlatched position).  That seems to have fully resolved the issue.

Comment: "reprogram" always seemed like an odd word in this context, like a bad translation

Comment: Typically you need enough time disconnected for the system to fully power down.  Capacitors and induction coils (used to smooth DC & AC power) can hold charge for a little while after losing power.  Usually 2-5 minutes is enough for most modern electronics.